# SSIS Packages to Application Insights

Tags: ssis, azure-application-insights

I was wondering if there was any way (potentially via a C# script) of exporting package data from a task in SSIS to application insights.

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish?  It seems that application Insights has a monitor that you would install on your vm's to collect data from the logs.  Where would SSIS fit in?

Comment: My company has an SSIS ETL that takes data from a bunch of different sources and transforms all that data to be used elsewhere. The logging information controlling the metrics and performance of the ETL needs to be exported to App Insights because monitoring all that same information in App insights would allow for Application Maps and useful info

Comment: Is it a question about how to get data from SSIS? Or how to ingest data to Application Insights?

Comment: My question is both. What I'm trying to do is model my SSIS package onto the Application Map under application insights.

Comment: @Joey Did you find anything on this?

Comment: @Garuda all that I found was that within a C# script you can send telemetry info to application insights using a telemetry client object. The track event method I believe allows you to pass in a dictionary of key value pairs.

Comment: @Joey probably that's the way to go. Did you find anything else since then?